# Can not fetch array data using post methos in PHP and Angular.js

Tags: php, angularjs, arrays

I have an issue. I am submitting a form using Angular.js and PHP. I am sending array of data to server side using `$http` service but in serverside i am not getting any value. I am explaining my code below.

```
var supplierData=$("#billdata").serialize();
supplierData+= "&image="+newpath+"&action=add"+"&special="+$scope.example14model;
$http({
    method:'POST',
    url:"php/customerInfo.php",
    data:supplierData,
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
}).then(function successCallback(response){
  console.log('respon',response.data);
},function errorCallback(response) {
})
```

Here this `$scope.example14model` is taking array of data like below.

```
$scope.example14model=[
         {'id':1},
         {'id':2}
]
```

While I am fetching these data in server side like below

```
$mulspec=$_POST['special'];
```

Its not giving any data but showing like `[object Object],[object Object]` while printing this value. I need to get all array data here. Please help me.

Comment: You are using a javascript object as a string (`+$scope.example14model`).You'll probably want to serialize it in some way, for example by using `JSON.stringify(...)`.

Comment: Shouldn't it print `respon[object Object][object Object]`? Do you want to print it or store it in a variable? You can use `JSON.stringify()` like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/steu4w5v/).

Answer (score 0):

When you do the following:

```
"&special="+$scope.example14model
```

it is just doing a toString on the example14model property and by default this will give you what you are seeing. I think what you need to do is convert it to json. Try:

```
"&special="+JSON.stringify($scope.example14model)
```

This will come through on the server side as a json string so you may need to do some serialization to an object, depending on what you want to do with it.

Update after comment.
I haven't worked with JSON in PHP myself but to get an object from the data I think the following will work.

```
$json=$_POST['special'];
$mulspec=json_decode($json);

echo(count($mulspec));
```

You should now be able to count the items in the array

Comment: i did as per you and got value like `[{"id":"1"},{"id":"2"}]` this but i am counting the no of values using `echo(count($mulspec));` its showing `1` but it should be `2`.

Comment: The result you have there is a string so count will only give 1 as its a single object. I haven't done it myself in PHP but you will need to deserialize that value into an array and then get the count of that array. Had a quick search and I think this could help. http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php